# regex expression to include german characters

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, regexp-replace, regexp-substr

I have a string that looks like this:

```
{"id":"1","name":"simpleword","type":"test"},{"id":"123","name":"f23ÜÜ","type":"prod"}
```

I want to do a `REGEXP_SUBSTR_ALL` such that I can extract all "name" values into a list.

Something like this allows me to extract some names but not all. This is because some names include german characters like "Ü" which are not included with '\w+'

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR_ALL(ARRAY_TO_STRING(REGEXP_SUBSTR_ALL((ARRAY_TO_STRING(REGEXP_SUBSTR_ALL(ARTICLE_TAGS, '"name\\W+\\w+"'),',')), ':"\\w+'),','),'\\w+') FROM TABLE
```

For example, the expression above would give me this output:

```
[
    "simpleword"
]
```

while my desired output is this:

```
[
    "simpleword", "f23ÜÜ"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just match everything that is not a `"`:

```sql
with data(s) as (
    select $${"id":"1","name":"simpleword","type":"test"},{"id":"123","name":"f23ÜÜ","type":"prod"}$$
)

select regexp_substr_all(s, 'name":"([^"]*)"', 1, 1, '', 1)
from data

-- [   "simpleword",   "f23ÜÜ" ]
```

Also an alternative (as discussed in the comments, with the 'e' `regex_parameters`:

```sql
with data(s) as (
    select $${"id":"1","name":"simpleword","type":"test"},{"id":"123","name":"f23ÜÜ","type":"prod"}$$
)

select regexp_substr_all(s, 'name":"([^"]*)"', 1, 1, 'e')
from data
```

Comment: Could you also please explain the regex?

Comment: what's the 1, 1, '', 1 part doing?

Comment: From the docs (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr_all.html#syntax): `REGEXP_SUBSTR_ALL( <subject> , <pattern> [ , <position> [ , <occurrence> [ , <regex_parameters> [ , <group_num> ] ] ] ] )` -- we need group 1 (between parenthesis), which is the last parameter

Comment: i understand the subject and pattern. But how's the position helping here? Isn't it position 1 by default too? And if we write "1" as occurence then how do we get all occurrences of the names? and what '' is doing as the regex parameter? its not in the accepted items in the docs

Comment: They are all placeholders (default), so I can get that last 1 in (because that's the 1 I need for `group_num`). Also I took a second look, and I like how `'e'` works in this case. See the updated answer.